# Rails ajax post with simple form: why GET request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create an ajax update action with simple form and I don't know why the browser fire a "get" request instead of a "patch".

In my view I have

```
= simple_form_for current_user, url: certificate_webex_employee_path(current_user), remote: true, html: { class: 'edit-profile' }, defaults: { label: false } do |f|
          .form-body
            .form-group.row
              .col-md-12{style: 'color: black'}
                = f.input_field :webex_certification_code, class: "form-control"
```

My routes.rb

```
resources :users, controller: 'employees', path: 'employees', as: 'employees', only: [:index, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy] do
    get :performance, on: :collection
    member do
      patch :certificate_webex
    end
  end
```

And of course in the controller I have the `certificate_webex` method.

Why when I submit the action is "Request Method:GET" ???
The `certificate_webex` method is not called by my form.

**edit**

I try also with

```
=form_for current_user, url: certificate_webex_employee_path(current_user), method: :patch, remote: true, html: { class: 'edit-profile' }, defaults: { label: false } do |f|
 = f.text_field :webex_certification_code, class: "form-control"
```

Comment: are you sending the form by clicking `f.submit` button or customized button with javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the method in the form_for

```
:method => :patch
```

I haven't used the simple_form_for gem but the default rails form_for docs refer to this here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: The same, always :get even if I use form for and I specify.

Comment: Is it possible in your routes you need to add patch to the only: [:index, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy] ?